# Passing data from JS to Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

i have a parameter in my function JS .. The goal is when i click on my button the  parameter should be assigned on new variable Laravel  .. i want to pass my data from JS to Laravel

```
<script type="text/javascript"  >

    function change_theme(color) {

        {{ $idc = color }}//somthing like this 

        document.getElementById('iframe').setAttribute("src","{{(route('generate.pdfColor', ['slug' => 'student', 'id' => '56', 'color' => '$idc']))}}");
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Why you want to do it?if this variable change frontend elements you can do it whith events of javascript . If this variable will be sent to any action of controller you can define hidden input and populate its value by javascript and pass it. If you describe more about your goal we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change_theme(color) {
    var url = "{{(route('generate.pdfColor', ['slug' => 'student', 'id' => '56', 'color' => ':id']))}}";
        url = url.replace('%3Aid',color);
        document.getElementById('iframe').setAttribute("src", url);
    }
</script>
```